# Facing issues after importing maven project into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsp

I import the project successfully into eclipse but encountered by many issues.I solved those issues like

1. set the jre environment for project
2. updated maven for project
3. updated tomcat
4. created folder text/java under src

After removing all error when I am running the project on server showing error .

[image: Error page]

and unable to map jsp with servlet
Please help with some solution I tried many ways but still on same track

Comment: Look at the information you've provided. There is nothing here that anyone could use to diagnose your problem. You'll need to show all relevant details of your project.

Comment: @David M karr I am asking what are the possible reasons are there that I am not able run the jsp page on server. When I mapped src as source folder for project It only showing index page when that page caling servlet showing above error

Comment: I done all the necessary updates that eclipse ask me for but still some issues are there I am not getting

Comment: What I'm telling you is that there are numerous reasons this could be going wrong, and asking someone to enumerate all of them is pointless. What you should be doing is showing the actual details of your project, and then it might be obvious to someone.

Comment: I solved this issue there was error in sequence